# Not able to modify fragment data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following fragment working in view pager:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/window_background"
android:id="@+id/font"
tools:context="com.cuentos.lib.cuentosmusicales.Libro">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/titleBook"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#2211CC"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleBook"
    android:id="@+id/textBook"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#44BB11"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and i want to modify textview values from fragment class

```
public class Libro extends Fragment {
String titleLibro;
String text;
TextView title, text1;

public Libro() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_libro, container, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleBook);
    text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBook);

    title.setText("hi friends");
    text1.setText("text");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_libro, container, false);
   }
}
```

So, I detect im not able to change data because there is no change, so how I can instanciate textview in fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're inflating your view two times. There's one on the first line of the onCreateView, which is the one that you modify the TextViews, but in the return statement you create and return another, you're not returning the one you modified, but a new one instead, so the view that will be presented in the UI is the not modified.

Also, you're calling the findViewById in the wrong lifecycle stage. Notice that onCreateView returns the view that will be present in your fragment. It's not possible to retrieve a view component like yours TextViews that way, because the view itself doesn't exists yet.

The right method to modify your view components is in the onViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleBook);
    text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBook);

    title.setText("hi friends");
    text1.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text when overriding your Fragments `onActivityCreated` or `onResume` methods.

Comment: sorry I hadn´t set the " " but I´ve update my code, check again please